# How to get a user by username from WordPress with Rest API?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm attempting to retrieve a user from my WordPress website using its username via the REST API. I've used the endpoint `https://my-website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users?search=my-username`, but I'm consistently receiving an empty array as a response.

I've double-checked the username, and I'm certain it exists on the WordPress website. Despite this, I'm not sure why I'm not getting the expected response.

Comment: Is `/wp-json/wp/v2/users` getting you anything at all?

Comment: It returns some user's information, But a few of them.

Comment: Well the default `per_page` limit is 10. // Documentation only describes the search parameter with _"limit results to those matching a string"_, but doesn't explain what properties actually get matched against - although I would expect the username to be one of them.

Comment: I got your point. You mean the username is searched only in those default 10 records.
What should I do to search for all of them?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant, I was just giving you the explanation for "It returns some user's information, But a few of them." Filtering the results via the search parameter should happen _before_ the limit is applied, everything else makes little sense.

Comment: Aha, I understand. You right. But it's not a good solution for a website with more than 5000 users to search in 50 pages ( Each page can have a maximum of 100 records )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257170/discussion-between-smh-lotfizadeh-and-cbroe).